# Convert backslash-escaped characters to literals, within a string

Tags: c#, .net

Are there any .NET provided functions to convert a string with backslash-escaped characters into the literal string?
For example, the string `@"this\x20is a\ntest"` should become `"this is a\ntest"`, where `\n` is a literal newline character and `\x20` is a literal space. These would (preferably) be [Microsoft escape characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Regex.Unescape

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

string result=Regex.Unescape(@"this\x20is a\ntest");
```

This results in:

```
this is a 
test
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/y2f5GE

It might not work all the time as expected, please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=netframework-4.7.2) for details